# Lualatex don't work after updates

Tags: luatex, linux, luaotfload, texlive-2021

After updating texlive2021 all documents don't compile anymore and I get these error messages in the logfile:

```
luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR
luaotfload | load :   × Failed to load "luaotfload" module "features".
luaotfload | load :   × Error message:
luaotfload | load :     × "...xmf-dist/tex/lualatex/uninormalize/lua-uni-normal
ize.lua:36: module 'lua-uni-parse' not found:".
luaotfload | load :     × "no field package.preload['lua-uni-parse']".
luaotfload | load :     × "[kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'lua-uni-parse'"
```

Maybee the error is caused by an update of the OS itself (Linux Mint 20.3 with kernel 5.4.0-100). Unlike usual, I didn't find any up-to-date, comparable description of the error when I searched the net.

Comment: install the lua-uni-algos package.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636031/lualatex-dont-work-after-updates#comment1585181_636031), the modules `lua-uni-case`, `lua-uni-normalize`, `lua-uni-graphemes` etc. are provided by the [lua-uni-algos](https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-uni-algos) package.